# JSoup Java URLs with spaces (double encoding error)

Tags: java, url, jsoup

thanks for the help so far.

My first question is 
        'Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();' what encoding and decoding normally happens in this operation.  For example, can I give it utf-8 or utf-16 (with latest JSoup library).

My second question is the following url:

```
      String url = "http://www.chestertons.com/property-to-buy/search-results/properties-in-london-england-to-buy/b-t-llondon, england/?pagesize=60"
```

If you scroll there is a space before england, I tried encoding the space to UTF-8 but the Jsoup parser double encodes the URL and I need to do this because Jsoup does not like spaces at all.

The full code is:

```
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Chrome/41.0.2228.0 "
                + "(Windows NT 6.1)"
                + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mozilla/5.0 "
                + "Safari/537.36").timeout(14000).followRedirects(false).
                ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

And the error I'm getting from the console is:

```
     SEVERE: IO exception from crawling 
    org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.chestertons.com/property-to-buy/search-results/properties-in-london-england-to-buy/b-t-llondon%252C%2520england/?pagesize=60
```

Any help or insight into the problem would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the right wording and judging by other posts it is not "eindeutig".

here is my work around:

```
     Document doc;
        doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(getUrl()).openStream(),  "ISO-8859-1", getUrl());
```

Now my only problem is how do I avoid redirects and ignore the content type (possibly) by using parse instead.  This is the only way I can see to get the work around.